# Delphi android application crash after a few

Tags: delphi

I have developed an android app that will run in some Asus Android 7 tablets in a firm but I find a very weird behavior. This application is very small and easy; it has:

1. A button to store 2 string values taken from 2 edits
2. A TTabControl with 3 pages and each of them has a TWebBrowser inside.
3. A button on the top to execute some javascript code.

You can see a picture [here](http://prntscr.com/g0ilx2) taken from win32. Below there is the code which is pretty easy and (I guess) without errors. I am under firemonkey of course.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
     // ... declarations ...
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FLinea: string;
    list: TStringList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

//I take the text from the 3 edits you can see above (picture) and I save a txt file
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var salva: TStringList;
begin

 /*just for debug purpose...*/
 if ( (Length(EditLinea.Text) > 0) and (Length(EditOperatore.Text) > 0) and (Password.Text = 'abc123') ) then
  begin

   FLinea := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'operatore.txt');
   salva := TStringList.Create;

   salva.Add(EditLinea.Text);
   salva.Add(EditOperatore.Text);
   salva.SaveToFile(FLinea);

   ShowMessage('Saved! Restart the app.');

  end
 else
  begin
   ShowMessage('Wrong password!');
  end;

end;

//when I press the STOP button above I execute a javascript function that is defined in the page loaded in the browser
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 WebBrowser.EvaluateJavaScript('stopExec();');
end;

//Here I just check if a txt file exists and I load it
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

 //HERE I CHECK IF THERE IS A TXT FILE THAT I NEED TO LOAD
 FLinea := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'operatore.txt');

 if (FileExists(FLinea)) then
  begin

   list := TStringList.Create;
   list.LoadFromFile(FLinea);

   LabelImpiegato.Text := 'OPERATORE '+list.Strings[1];
   WebBrowser.URL := 'www.aaa.com/loader.php?linea='+list.Strings[0]+'&operat='+list.Strings[1];
   WebBrowser.EnableCaching := false;
   WebBrowser.Navigate;

  end
 else
  begin

   //error
   TabControl.Visible := false;
   Error.Visible := true;

  end;

end;
```

**Problem:** the application works correctly but after some time (in general 10/15 min) it crashes. The error message is "The application has suddenly stopped". Could it be something wrong with my code?

I really doubt that it might be a power-saving configuration on the tablet. I really don't know what to do because I was looking for something like a form `OnException` property but no luck.

Could it be the javascript code that clashes with TWebBrowser? Look:

```
function start() {
 myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
 myVar2 = setInterval(orologio, 1000);
}
```

Basically that is a function that is called when the page opens (body onload) and the setInterval is like the delphi `TTimer`. With a period of 1000ms it executes the function on 1st argument. It works perfectly on Firefox and as Win32 app.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, this is an issue that is not related to Delphi (or javascript). The application crashes due to an update of Google's `Webview` service that is causing problems on applications like the one I have (applications with a web browser inside).

I have uninstalled the updates on Google's webview and now the application works properly. Of course Delphi's `TWebBrowser` relies on the webview service and so uninstalling the update was the solution.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a permanent "solution" of any kind, especially if this is something that people will download and use. This is only a temporary work-around.